# error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, qt, ogre

Trying to use Ogre in the Qt project. Ogre is build succesfully. Running the project it gives me three errors:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0:-1: error: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
-1: error: main.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
```

When I searched for the error it says to edit the makefile and adding:
LIBS =-lpthread

but it is already there.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 24):

You need to link boost library in your project.

Add `LIBS += -lboost_system` in your project's pro file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
I am using code blocks IDE and having the same error. I resolve it as below:

- In code blocks IDE goto settings > compiler.
- Under the "Linker Settings" tab add path : ***/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so***

Now build your program again.

Hope this will be usfull.

Comment: And what to do if I don't use Code::Blocks?